# Monitoring outgoing bandwidth of application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, bandwidth, optimization

I currently have a VPS that is consuming a ton of outgoing bandwidth and I am trying to drill down to where this may be coming from.  Does anyone know of a logical way to go about finding out which pages on the site are consuming the most outgoing data.  We have done a ton of front-end optimizations to the site and our google page speed rankings ar 85% so I feel we have done a pretty great job at optimizing the site for speed.

Can someone lend some insight on how they have made similar optimizations?

**Application / Server Stack**

- LEMP Running Varnish Cache / PHP5-FPM
- WordPress running w3 Total Cache
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: You can use google analytics to find out which page is getting a lot of traffic.

Comment: Thanks HackToHell this gives me some insight but not really enough.  Every night we get a steady stream of outbound traffic and I am having a hard time figuring where it is coming from.  GA is good in general but not really the perfect situation.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to ask. Are you trying to figure out which pages of the site are consuming the most outgoing data? Or do you want some insights on the optimization techniques? Both questions are quite different and if you want answers to both, please consider posting them separately.

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu I have done pretty much all the optimization that is possible.  I am looking on maybe some server side options for monitoring outbound traffic maybe by asset or page, etc.  Something with some more granular control and some data based on file size, etc.

Comment: do you have tshark installed on server ? or if not can you install ?

Answer (score 2):

You can analyze the access log files from your nginx, provided that you have different log files for different vhosts. Then you can write a simple script which extracts the important data from the logfiles. Maybe you can even find some suitable plugin for [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/).

Comment: This. A web search for "nginx log analysis" turns up several possibilities for packages which may tell you exactly what resources on your web site are using lots of bandwidth. Of course, if you have disabled logging of certain resources, then you'll have to re-enable it...